# Quickly send an email

Tags: email, to-do-list

I'm looking for a way to send an email to myself as quickly as possible. I am using my inbox as TODO list, and sometimes even send emails to myself to add new items…

The optimal solution would be one where after a single touch on homescreen and typing a line of text (like: “Buy Milk”), some app or service would automatically send an email to my address with subject equal to what I typed. I wish to avoid choosing destination address, being forced to type something into the body and so on.

I'm currently using Evernote for that, occasionally moving items to my INBOX manually. But even then it's 5 or 6 touches + several seconds needed to load Evernote on my a bit dated Milestone 1.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at e.g. [Mail Myself](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pfalabs) / [SelfMail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.javatomic.drupal) (which integrate into the Share menu), or [Email Me](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caramellabs.emailme) / [Email To Self](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.emailtoself):

> Create homescreen shortcuts which use a preselected email address and/or label by long pressing on a blank space on your homescreen, then select Shortcuts, then Email To Self.

Guess that's what you're looking for ;)

Comment: After pressing “Send” `Mail Myself` still goes into my default email app (k9mail), so that's additional 2 touches. But it's better than using Evernote… Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! There are more/similar apps on the playstore, maybe one of them does a better job? Check e.g. [Email Me](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caramellabs.emailme) or [SelfMail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.javatomic.drupal) (the latter again a candidate for the "Share menu")?

Comment: I checked few apps, and settled on `Mail Myself`. These apps have surprisingly many problems for my case: I don't use GMail, which eliminated one of them; the ones that send emails on their own don't use encryption, so email password would leak out; one of them also lost my message when it was unable to contact the server…

Comment: Would you mind to point out which was which? I'd update my answer then to include those details, which might prove helpful to others.

Comment: I haven't taken notes, sorry. But skimming over lowest-rated comments on all those apps seems to agree with what I found.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Voice Actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/) has what you want.

Simply enter voice command mode, say "note to self", then say whatever your note is. When you're done an email message will be sent to you with the text of your message.

Comment: +1 - the "note to self" feature is very handy. These actions are built into Google Search in Jelly Bean (and I believe ICS, possibly older versions as well).

Comment: I remember doing it on my Droid, which never got past 2.2.

Comment: My phone is not set to English, which seems to be required by Voice Actions.

Comment: I tested on my daughter's Droid Incredible 2 (Android 2.3) and that requires hitting "Send" after it translates your speech. On my Galaxy Nexus (4.1) it sends the message automatically once it figures out you've stopped speaking.